# Template argument deduction order

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Can anybody explain why the following code does not compile:

```
template <typename P>
struct Base
{
    friend typename P::One;
    friend typename P::Two;
    friend typename P::Three;
};

template<typename U, typename D, typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<Derived<U,D,T>>
{
    using One   = U;
    using Two   = D;
    using Three = T;
};
```

The error is:

```
..\PRP\main.cpp:3:1: error: no type named 'One' in 'struct Derived<A, B, C>'
 {
 ^
..\PRP\main.cpp:3:1: error: no type named 'Two' in 'struct Derived<A, B, C>'
..\PRP\main.cpp:3:1: error: no type named 'Three' in 'struct Derived<A, B, C>'
```

And why the following code compile perfectly:

```
template <typename T>
struct Sum
{
    constexpr static int sze = T::uno + T::due + T::tre;
};

template<int i, int j, int k>
struct Triple : public Sum<Triple<i, j, k>>
{
    constexpr static int uno = i;
    constexpr static int due = j;
    constexpr static int tre = k;
};
```

What are the differences between the two? I think it is something related to the template deduction order but I could be wrong.

I'm using MinGW 4.8 on Win7 with flag C++11 on.
Thanks!

Comment: @ForEveR, are you actually instantiating the template? (The OP should have included complete code to reproduce the error, including an instantiation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no template argument deduction happening in your code, so this has nothing to do with deduction.

The problem is caused by trying to use members of `Derived` while it is an incomplete type.

The friend declarations are processed immediately by the compiler during the instantiation of `Base<Derived<U,D,T>>` which occurs in the base class list of `Derived`, and at that point `Derived` is incomplete, so trying to use its members is not possible.

The static member in `Sum` is not instantiated automatically, and isn't needed in the declaration of `Triple`. If you use the static member later on then `Triple` is a complete type and its members can be referred to.

If you try to use `Sum<T>::sze` in the definition of `Sum` you will get a similar error, because `T` is not a complete type at that point:

```
template <typename T>
struct Sum
{
    constexpr static int sze = T::uno + T::due + T::tre;
    char buf[sze];
};

template<int i, int j, int k>
struct Triple : public Sum<Triple<i, j, k>>
{
    constexpr static int uno = i;
    constexpr static int due = j;
    constexpr static int tre = k;
};

Triple<1, 2, 3> t;
```

Comment: Ok, understood! Your example with 'char buf[size]' has completely marked the line between what is necessary for the type definition and what is just declaration (like the static variable size). I'd have never said that a friendship relation could be something that important in this phase of compilation.

Comment: Friend declarations might introduce new names into the enclosing namespace, and there isn't really a better time when they would get processed, so it happens as soon as the compiler encounters them.